# Remove attribute value from WooCommerce product using CRUD operation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, crud, hook-woocommerce

I have an global attribute `pa_status` with values such as `new`, `old`, `custom`.
This attribute is used in my products.

I would like to remove the `old` value from a product using the [CRUD](https://woocommerce.com/document/developing-using-woocommerce-crud-objects/) operations available in WooCommerce.

The current code looks like this and doesn't work:

```
$id_product = 77233;
$attribute_name = 'pa_status';
$attribute_value_to_remove_by_id = 57;

$product = wc_get_product($id_product);
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if (isset($attributes[$attribute_name])) {
    $attributes[$attribute_name]['options'] = array_filter(
        $attributes[$attribute_name]['options'],
        function ($value) use ($attribute_value_to_remove_by_id) {
            return $value !== $attribute_value_to_remove_by_id;
        }
    );
}

$product->set_attributes($attributes);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Why not remove it from the attribute terms?

Comment: I don't want to remove them completely, because I still need them in other products.

Comment: Why not remove it from the products page if it is only for one item?

Comment: I have to do it with php and then set it as a cron task. This is part of a larger case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced through **xDebug** what is happening in the `save()` method and it looks like the `get_changes()` method from `WC_Product` returns nothing. So no change is taking place in the DB

We need to create an instance of the `WC_Product_Attribute` class, and then perform operations on this object.

Now it seems to be working properly. Corrected code:

```
$id_product = 77233;
$attribute_name = 'pa_status';
$attribute_value_to_remove_by_id = 57;

$product = wc_get_product($id_product);
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
$options = [];

if (isset($attributes[$attribute_name])) {
    $options = array_filter(
        $attributes[$attribute_name]['options'],
        function ($value) use ($attribute_value_to_remove_by_id) {
            return $value !== $attribute_value_to_remove_by_id;
        }
    );
}

$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_id(wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($attribute_name));
$attribute->set_name($attribute_name);
$attribute->set_options($options);
$attributes[$attribute_name] = $attribute;

$product->set_attributes($attributes);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

@kanlukasz,

You should be able to remove an Attributes of a single item from the products page.

[image]

Remove the old option from attribute pa_status from this page and save the item.

I hope this helps.

Reference:

https://learnwoo.com/woocommerce-attributes-variations/

Comment: I hope you are joking. I have to do it with php and then set it as a cron task. This is part of a larger case. If I could remove it for myself through the admin panel then I would never ask such a question here...

Comment: @kanlukasz, your question does not mention needing to do it programmatically or anything about a Cron job. Take a look at this post see if this helps: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334537/how-to-remove-product-attribute-row-woocommerce-using-code

Comment: i thought it was obvious because I posted a code example. Anyway, I edited the title and content to be more specific. Sorry for the confusion